# What's the idiomatic verb that goes together with the fulfilling of a promise?

Tags: idiom-request

What's the idiomatic verb that goes together with the fulfilling of a promise?

Some example I thought of - are:

> 1. Please, if you promise something, then _____ it.
> 2. He always _____ his promises.
> 3. I don't like to promise promises if I don't know for sure that I'll____ them.
> 4. It's very good to promise promises but it's even better to____ them.

The words that I can think of are: fulfill, do, make it true.

Comment: This is homework, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the answer is: not at all. It's original 100% by me. These are problems that I might come across everyday. Basically I used always the word "**do**" in this context, but today I decided to check it out.

Comment: Ah right. I should have read more carefully. To make a promise. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## keep a promise (do not break it)

Keep can [mean](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep) "to be faithful to":

> 1. Please, if you promise something, then **keep** it.
> 2. He always **keeps** his promises.
> 3. I don't like to promise promises if I don't know for sure that I'll **be able to keep** them.
> 4. It's very good to promise promises but it's even better to **keep** them.

The opposite of keeping a promise would be to **break a promise**:

> 1. Please, if you promise something, then **do not break** it.
> 2. He **never breaks** his promises.
> 3. I don't like to promise promises if I don't know for sure that I **won't break** them.
> 4. It's very good to promise promises but it's even better to **not break** them.

Comment: Sentence 1 is not correct.  The antecedent of "it" is "something," so your sentence means "if you promise [to do] something, then keep that thing."  Promises are kept, but only when they're nouns, not verbs.

Comment: As a footnote, we could get around the somewhat awkward "promise promises" by using the verb _make_, as in:  _I don't like to **make** promises if I don't know for sure that I'll be able to keep them._ @Juhasz - The verb _make_ could fix the problem you've pointed out, too: _Please, if you make a promise, then keep it._